# tableView in UITableViewController is nil after init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have following code in a subclass of UITableViewController. Under iOS 5.1 it works fine, but under iOS 6, self.tableView is nil (both in simulator and on real device). Am I doing it wrong? Why isn't the view set straight away after the init?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self) 
    {
        UIView * bck = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [bck setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = bck;
        [bck release];
    }

    return self;
}
```

EDIT:

I've nailed down the problem:

I've got class

```
AccountsListViewController_iPad
```

which is subclass of

```
AccountsListViewController : UITableViewController
```

AccountsListViewController has it's tableView & view loaded after init (as I would expect). AccountsListViewController_iPad on the other hand has it's view and tableView equal to nil. I've removed everything from AccountsListViewController_iPad so now it looks as follows:

```
.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AccountsListViewController.h"
@interface AccountsListViewController_iPad : AccountsListViewController
@end

.m
#import "AccountsListViewController_iPad.h"
@implementation AccountsListViewController_iPad
@end
```

And still it's view is nil. In my opinion, it should behave exactly the same as its superclass, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've worked it out:

There was AccountsListViewController_iPad class and associated AccountsListViewController_iPad.xib file. Xib, despite not being loaded anywhere in the code and file owner in xib not being AccountsListViewController_iPad, was still being loaded. For some reason, the table view in xib was set to property 'table' in file owner (which didn't exist) and hence view and tableView were nil.

I still don't know why the xib was loaded or why it issue exist happen under iOS 5.x

Comment: That was it. When I created the xib using the "New File -> Cocoa Touch Class" it happened.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is because the table view is not load until the view is loaded. You should move the view setup to `viewDidLoad`.

The only 'view' property you should set up in `init` methods is `.navigationItem` (although I think `UINavigationItem` is probably best considered part of the controller rather than view).

Comment: That's what I think. What I don't understand is why this suddenly stopped working in iOS 6? Or is it something that worked just by chance?

Comment: @Rafał I suspect that prior to iOS 6 the tableView was lazy loaded in the getter but now it is loaded in `loadView`. (I suspect you could force `tableView` to load by calling `self.view;` prior to `self.tableView.backgroundView = bck;`. But don't do that, do it the proper way and use `viewDidLoad`.)